# receiving Google docs form data in email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have used multiple scripts that I've found all over the web, and am running into the same problem.  I have several google docs forms that I need to receive the submitted data by email (not just a notification that the form has been submitted and the corresponding spreadsheet has been updated).  This script WAS working, but has stopped for some reason:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    
// Remember to replace XYZ with your own email address
var email = "info.wchs@gmail.com"; 

// Optional but change the following variable
// to have a custom subject for Google Docs emails
var subject = "Google Docs Form Submitted";  

// The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
// Loop through the array and append values to the body.

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
var message = "";    

// Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order

for(var i in headers)
  message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 

// This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
// that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp here.

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

// By Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org
}
```

To which I receive an error: TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 20)

I've changed nothing and now I can't find any form-submit to email script to work.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some debugging there, inserting test cases until your resolve your issue, for example, like you are getting a `line 20` error for `namedValues`,  check `e` before accessing it like this:

```
for(var i in headers)
    if (e && e.namedValues)
       message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of blank data in some columns . I'd suggest delete/remove all your existing triggers for the form , then use below code (I referred to code By Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org  )

```
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  // Loop through the array and append values to the body.
  try 
  {      
    // You may replace this with another email address
    var email = "xyw@mail.com";

    // Optional but change the following variable
    // to have a custom subject for Google Form email notifications
    var subject = "Training Application Form Submitted";  

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";    

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var i in columns ) 
    {
      var header = columns[i];
      if ( e.namedValues[header] && (e.namedValues[header] != "") ) 
      {
        message += header + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[header] + "\n\n"; 
      }
    }
    // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp for HTML Mail.

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  } 
  catch (e) 
  {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

}
```

Then just Save, Run the Initilize function, Accept the permissions.